# Which statement is true about the following sequence: $f(1)=1,f(2n)=f(n),f(2n+1)=f(n)+f(n+1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

ETA: In case someone notices the similarity, this question is *not* a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707021/arithmetic-function).

> Which statement is true about the sequence $\{f(n)\}$:
>    $$
> \left\{ 
> \begin{array}{l}
> f(1)=1 \\ 
> f(2n)=f(n) \\ 
> f(2n+1)=f(n)+f(n+1)
> \end{array}
> \right. 
> $$
>   a)All prime numbers appear in $\{f(n)\}$
>   b)All Mersen primes appear in $\{f(n)\}$
>   c)A finite set of primes appear in $\{f(n)\}$
>   d)Just primes of the form $4t-1$ appear in $\{f(n)\}$

It's seen that $f(2n)=1$ but I'm not sure that $f(2n+1)$ generates which primes...

Comment: Is $f(n+1)_3$ a typo ?

Comment: @zwim Yes,sorry,I fix it

Comment: Have you made a spreadsheet and computed the first few dozen terms?  Your statement that $f(2n)=1$ is not true.  For example $f(6) \neq 1$.  You have $f(6)=f(3)=f(1)+f(2)=2$

Comment: @RossMillikan You are right,I made a mistake...

Comment: No even the formulation is different $f(2n)=n$ vs $f(2n)=f(n)$. I've run it for the first 2000 terms, seems to me that your function fills $\mathbb N$.

Comment: This is [OEIS sequence A002487](https://oeis.org/A002487).  Note in particular the comment starting "If the terms are written as an array:".

Comment: @zwim You are right, missed the symbol.... removed

Comment: The question is probably not asking "exactly one of these is true; which is it", because then the answer couldn't be A. That would imply B and C. So the question is probably asking "which (possibly several) of these statements are true". And you already know that C is true, because $f(3) = 2$ and $\{2\}$ is a finite set of primes.

Comment: Why has this been marked as a duplicate?!  The linked question is *not* a duplicate—as zwim noted, the function isn't the same, and the question being asked about the function is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** Consider the values of $f(2^m)$, for $m \geq 0$.  What values are taken on by that subsequence?

Now consider the values of $f(2^m+1)$, for $m \geq 0$.  What values are taken on by that subsequence?

Comment: $f(2^m)=1$ and $f(2^m+1)=f(2^{m-1})+f(2^{m-1}+1)$ but I can't go on

Comment: What are the first few values of $f(2^m+1)$? What are $f(3), f(5), f(9)$,...?

Comment: $f(3)=2,f(5)=3,f(7)=3,f(9)=4,f(11)=5$...

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi The question was not just for fun. Do you notice anything about the numbers you've written down?

Comment: Not all odd numbers, just the powers of two plus 1. I didn't ask about $f(7)$ or $f(11)$ for a reason.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs It seems the subsequence  $\{f(2^m+1)\}$ generates all positive integers starting from 2 but it MUST be proved

Comment: Well, do you know how to write an induction proof? If you define the statement $P(n)$ as: "$f(2^n)=1$ and $f(2^n+1)=n+1$", that's something you can prove by induction.

Comment: Yes, I think induction makes it's proof easy . Thank you